# ASP.NET Core IISIntegration.Tools and .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, dll, asp.net-core, .net-core

In the ASP.NET Core 1.0 I was using:

> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools":
>   "1.0.0-preview2-final"

To run dotnet publish commands, but in the ASP.NET Core 1.1 I'm starting to get the following error:

> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools
>   1.1.0-preview4-final is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Package
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final
>   supports: netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)

How can I still use "dotnet-publish-iis" with ASP.NET Core and regular .NET frameworks?

project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Dapper": "1.50.2",
    "log4net": "2.0.5",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net462": {}
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "appsettings.json",
      "log4net.xml",
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "configurations": {
    "Debug": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [
          "DEBUG",
          "TRACE"
        ]
      }
    },
    "Integration": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [
          "DEBUG",
          "TRACE"
        ]
      }
    },
    "Production": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [ "RELEASE", "TRACE" ],
        "optimize": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your project.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Update all packages to version 1.1.0 (and the corresponding previews for tools)

2) Tools packages should be installed into the `tools` section of `project.json`, not `dependencies`.

Hence, make sure you have added `IISIntegration.Tools` under tools section of `project.json` like this-

```
"tools": {
    ....
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    ....
```

3) Remove old `project.lock.json` and run `dotnet restore` again.

4) Now you can publish using - `dotnet publish`

See if this helps.

Comment: *Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2).* I'll add a copy of my project.json...

Comment: @J.Lennon Remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools` from dependencies. Refer my point no.2.